# Create hash generator with configurable hash algorithm

Tags: c#

Create hash generator with configurable hash algorithm. Also need method to create salt. Implemented in visual studio 2015. Must work in DNX Core 5.0.

```
 public class HashGenerator : IHashGenerator
    {
        // Algorithm has to inherit from HashAlgorithm base class.
        // For example, another algorithm that can be used is: "System.Security.Cryptography.MD5";
        private const string HashAlgorithmName = "System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256";

        public string GenerateHash(string input, string salt)
        {
            var saltedPassword = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{input}{salt}");

            var hashAlgorithm = GetHashAlgorithm();
            var hashedPassword = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(saltedPassword);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashedPassword);
        }

        public string CreateSalt()
        {
            var buffer = new byte[25];
            using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
            {
                rng.GetBytes(buffer);
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
        }

        private HashAlgorithm GetHashAlgorithm()
        {
            var typeInfo = Type.GetType(HashAlgorithmName).GetTypeInfo();
            var createMethod = typeInfo.GetDeclaredMethods("Create").First(f => f.GetParameters().Count() == 0);
            var hashAlgorithm = (HashAlgorithm)createMethod.Invoke(null, null);
            return hashAlgorithm;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now you're stuck with the use of a constant. `GetHashAlgorithm` should receive, as a parameter, a `Type`. You then have 3 options for method signature :

The first one has the advantage of being sure that the `Type` inherits `HashAlgorithm`.

```
string GetHashAlgorithm<T>() where T : HashAlgorithm
string GetHashAlgorithm(Type hashAlgorithmType)
string GetHashAlgorithm(string typeName)
```

You shouldn't use a constant, as it is... constant. You then need to recompile your code to change the algorithm, which isn't good.

You could retrieve this string from your `app.config` file, which means you could configure it without recompiling.

If you don't mind being stuck with constant algorithm, I still don't think you should `const` them. Retrieve the `HashAlgorithm` from a `factory` maybe :

```
public class HashAlgorithmFactory
{
    public HashAlgorithm Create(/*Parameters to decide which algorithm maybe?*/)
    {
        //Conditions to decide which algorithm to return according to parameter
        return SHA256.Create();
    }
}
```

Also, is there a reason why you don't use your method `CreateSalt` in your `CreateHash` method instead of providing a `salt` parameter? I think it would make sense, but I don't have full knowledge of your needs.

Comment: The `CreateSalt` method is created outside *most* likely because you would save the salt with the hashed password, so that you can reverify the password against any input with that salt. If the salt were not returned, or not allowed to be specified, then it would leave the issue that you could never verify a new password against the current hash.